# UILocalNotification app crash when repeat interval set to hourly

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uilocalnotification, repeat

Otherrepeat intervals work fine, but when I set the notification to repeat hourly and the timer goes off, app just freezes, and can't reopen the app until I clear all the local notifications.

```
switch(repeatType) {
            case kRepeatHourly:
                notif.repeatInterval = NSHourCalendarUnit;
                break;
            case kRepeatDaily:
                notif.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;
                break;
            case kRepeatWeekly:
                notif.repeatInterval = NSWeekCalendarUnit;
                break;
            case kRepeatMonthly:
                notif.repeatInterval = NSMonthCalendarUnit;
                break;
            case kRepeatAnnually:
                notif.repeatInterval = NSYearCalendarUnit;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
```

Comment: can you please NSLog RepeatHourly Data and time.i think time shd not be updated

Comment: Do you mean NSLog(@"Notif: %@", notif); ?

Comment: Yes print [datePicker date];

Comment: I have set the notification to fire in one minute, and set repeat interval hourly, this is the NSLog of the notification description when UILocalNotification set: http://pastebin.com/xxBYmUAt

Comment: Sorry this NSLog is when I tested for minute repeat interval, but crash occured stil

Comment: This is hourly:
http://pastebin.com/4WfLp970

Comment: did you test on device or simulator

Comment: I have tested it on device

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24519/discussion-between-nimit-parekh-and-1337code)

Comment: if you are satisfy with my help then please approve answer and +1 vote.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)scheduleNotification {

    [reminderText resignFirstResponder];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];

    Class cls = NSClassFromString(@"UILocalNotification");
    if (cls != nil) {

        UILocalNotification *notif = [[cls alloc] init];
        notif.fireDate = [datePicker date];
        notif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

        notif.alertBody = @"Did you forget something?";
        notif.alertAction = @"Show me";
        notif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
        notif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;

        NSInteger index = [scheduleControl selectedSegmentIndex];
        switch (index) {
            case 1:
                notif.repeatInterval = NSMinuteCalendarUnit;
                break;
            case 2:
                notif.repeatInterval = NSHourCalendarUnit;
                break;
            case 3:
                notif.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;
                break;
            case 4:
                notif.repeatInterval = NSWeekCalendarUnit;
                break;
            default:
                notif.repeatInterval = 0;
                break;
        }

        NSDictionary *userDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:reminderText.text
                                                forKey:kRemindMeNotificationDataKey];
        notif.userInfo = userDict;

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notif];
        [notif release];
    }
}
```

For more detail download source code form [reference link here](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/09/13/repeating-an-ios-local-notification.html)

Comment: Can you please download demo project and check it out.